# How can I handle the remote server message by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, import, powershell-2.0, remote-server, powershell-ise

I created a short *PowerShell* scrtipt in order to import a .reg file (an ODBC) to another server session.

I faced to this warning/issue.
The message is this (below):

> The operation completed successfully.
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The operation completed successfully.:String) [], RemoteException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> + PSComputerName        : MYSERVERNAME
>
> NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException

The script, install without problem the .reg file, but constantly I get the message.

This is my code:

```
#PARAMETERS - Variables
$Serverlist = Get-Content C:\ServerList.txt

try 
{
     Foreach ($ServerName in $Serverlist)
     {  
         $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servername
         Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "Copying ODBC Driver for $servername"
         $copy_cmd = "C:\MYFILE.reg"            

         Copy-Item $copy_cmd \\$servername\C$\ -recurse -force;

         Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "ODBC Successfully copied on $servername"

         #$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servername
         Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
        
         #Start-Process

         reg import C:\CopiedFile.reg #This line generate the message           
         Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "ODBC was installed
}
catch
{
     Write-Host "ERROR" -Foregroundcolour Red 
     exit
}
```

I tried to incapsulate the `Invoke-Command` or `reg import` in to *try - catch* statement, but the message still appear. I used another command, instead `reg import`, but the nothing change.

I can use this command line, but I would like to catch the error.

```
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "ODBC is installed " } ##-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

There is any way to get the eventually error or handle the message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the try block does not generate a terminating error, it will not move into the Catch block. This is controlled by *`-ErrorAction`* parameter. So you can set

```
Invoke-Command Session $session -ScriptBlock {} -ErrorAction Stop
```

This will cause the *`Invoke-Command`* Cmdlet to generate **terminating errors**(if any error occurs) allowing catch block to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Abdul Niyas P M.  I added your suggested command, but I get the same message/warning. (anyway the file was imported and installed).

The operation completed successfully.

At C:MyScript.ps1:24 char:5
+     Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The operation completed successfully.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : MYSERVER

Comment: @ulisses Can you try to wrap the `reg import C:\CopiedFile.reg` within `Invoke-Expression "reg import C:\CopiedFile.reg" -ErrorAction Stop`?

Comment: Hi @Abdul Niyas P M thanks for your time. I used, but I get the same message.